# Entity Framework Core 3.1 max pool size was reached

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm receiving an error in a Net Core 3.1 application using Entity Framework I hope I can get help with:

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
> connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
> connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

The site works fine locally but when hosted on Azure with multiple users are on I get the above error so it seems like a performance issue. It happens even with a relatively low number of users on(15). Usually when there's about 70 requests within a minute.

I've set the Max Pool Size higher(up to 3000) which fixes the server crash but introduces 400 errors periodically throughout the application. Based on other answers this is not really a fix but a stopgap solution anyway.
Here's a pic of the open connections when idle after a few days:
[image]

I use lazy loading in my database but it is using EF Core Dependency Injection so that should open/close connections automatically no?

How can I debug which section of the code is causing issues in this case?

Here's an example of how we use dependency injection:

```
[Authorize(Policy = Role.Administrator)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LessonsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public LessonsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var lessons = _context.Lesson.Select(l => new LessonViewModel
        {
            Id = l.Id,
            Name = l.Name,
            Order = l.Order
        });

        return Ok(new { data = lessons });
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var lesson = await _context.Lesson.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Lesson.Remove(lesson);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}
```

Here's where I add the db context in Startup/ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContextConnectionString"));
        });
```

Comment: It's the code. Database connections and DbContext instances are supposed to be short lived, never cached in fields etc. That's why *all* tutorials show creating connections or contexts in a `using` block. Somehow, your code is leaking connections. Post the code that creates or closes those connections and contexts

Comment: You can't fix this by changing the connection pool size. This would only create more leaked connections, lead to more blocking, more deadlocks, more delays, eventually freezing the entire service. The limit is there to catch such situations before they result in in a freeze

Comment: `it is using EF Core Dependency Injection so that should open/close connections automatically no?` how? Where? DI will dispose only scoped objects. In a controller, the scope is the HTTP request, and creation, disposal, is handled by the ASP.NET Core middleware. If you create transient instances explicitly without disposing them, the DI won't know about them and won't dispose them

Comment: Adding that the sleeping connections may be either unused pooled connections or leaked connections. If many are not sleeping, that  may be due to query performance or blocking.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It uses dependency injection to dispose of the object right? I've put some example code up of how we access the context

Comment: @DanGuzman They are all sleeping except for the one I'm using to run the query

Comment: It would help if you showed how you're registering your `DbContexts` in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: @IanKemp Added now

Comment: Do you have multiple DbContext in your app sharing same connection string?

Comment: @IanGleeson found any solution on this?

Comment: @DevG The culprit for me was the 'MultipleActiveResultSets=true' in my database connection string. Setting it to false fixed the issue for me.